# API with buyBook method

Tags: java, api, swagger

I need some help, I'm creating an API, simple, with POST, GET... and there's a part where I need to find the ID already created, so having a check, if ID is found, it registers in an array . In a better context, this method would be to buyProduct, Register and find I already did it, now I needed it to be verified if the product is found add it to an array. My problem is that it is not validating correctly, if I register with ID 1 for example and do the search there in the buyBook method, it informs that it was not found, and if I put any other number it says that it was found, apart from that keep the body of the record I didn't want that

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/book/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")    
public ResponseEntity<Integer> saveBook(
        @RequestBody Books book)

        throws Exception {       
    System.out.println("Processing saveBook...");
    
    book.id = counter;
    
    mapBook.put(counter, book);
    
    counter++;
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok(book.id);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/book/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)    
public ResponseEntity<Books> search(
        @PathVariable("id") Integer id) 
        throws Exception {       
    System.out.println("Processing search id...");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(mapBook.get(id));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/buyBook/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)     
public ResponseEntity<Books> buyBook(@RequestBody Books book, @PathVariable("id") Integer id)

        throws Exception {       
            System.out.println("Processing buyBook...");
            
            if(book.getId() == id) {
                System.out.println("Found book");           
            }else {
                System.out.println("Don't found book");     
            }
    
            
            mapBook.put(counter, book);
            
            counter++;
            
            return ResponseEntity.ok(mapBook.get(id));
    
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the `id` in your DB?

Comment: in this case, there is no DB, it is an API made in memory, and leaving as an observation, in the GET method, he finds, it is in the PUT the problem.